# How to upload gallery or captured image to server in android

Tags: android, image

I am facing a problem while uploading an image to amazon `s3` server in Android.

I have created a bucket and I need to post the image to that bucket every time. When I try to post the image to that bucket for the first time it can post from next time on words its showing a messages like:

> The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the
>   specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.

Can I upload images in a single bucket and I tried to

```
s3Client.createBucket(Constants.getPictureBucket());

// Content type is determined by file extension.
PutObjectRequest por = new PutObjectRequest(Constants.getPictureBucket(), Constants.PICTURE_NAME, new java.io.File(filePath));
s3Client.putObject(por);
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/ check this link

Comment: I need it in asynctask. And clear exaplation. Could you please explaing it?

Comment: What have you done so far? What is the issue / errors you are having? Post your code and a logcat.

Comment: i put an +1 to balance that minus votes, since you made some effort before post your question, and for answer to your question i guess enough answers are posted

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you know how to take image from gallery.There are several steps through which you can upload a image in the server.Follow the below steps,

1.Get the Image from the gallery.

2.Convert the image to Bitmap and compress it to your desired format.

```
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.icon);
  ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, stream);
```

3.Convert the Bitmap to byte[] .

```
byte [] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
```

4.and then send it using `Http Post` request.

The link which I am referring is [this](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/).

This is the link which serves your exact need http://blog.3dmick.com/2012/06/android-app-for-uploading-images-on-server/

Answer (score 2):

Check out these:

1. [**Uploading files to HTTP server using POST on Android.**](http://stunningco.de/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)
2. [Android: Upload image or file using http POST multi-part](http://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/android-upload-image-or-file-using-http-post-multi-part/)

Please note that `data.getData()` won't work on Samsung devices. Use a pre-inserted `URI` instead .

Comment: Is it for http server?

Comment: I dont know about http server. works with php.

Comment: @Sri pls refer this too http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/04/25/android-upload-an-image-to-a-server/